# Tomcat installation error

Tags: java

Because I was bored and irritated by this persistent problem, I ended 
up doing what I seldom do, choosing "Ignore and Continue (Not 
Recommended)" in the list of options in the installation wizard. The 
installation then finishes, but localhost:8080 is not recognized in 
the browser.

Comment: So what was the persistent problem that you ignored?

Comment: @StephenC.  When iam installing the tomcat server at the time failed installation

Comment: I know that.  What I asked you was what was the persistent problem that you ignored.

Comment: @StephenC. "Failed to install Tomcat9 service. Check your settings and permissions. Ignore and Continue anyway (not recommended)? 
Choose
Abort, retry, ignore. 
Plz slove this problem

Comment: So ... did you check your permissions and settings?  You are not giving us much information here ...

Comment: @StephenC, When i am installing tomcat server i faced some issues, how to overcome this problem. "Failed to install Tomcat9 service. Check your settings and permissions. Ignore and Continue anyway (not recommended)? Choose Abort, retry, ignore. Plz slove this problem

Comment: "So ... did you check your permissions and settings? You are not giving us much information here ... ".  Also, did you check that the Tomcat service is running.